# Hierarchical Clustering with cosine similarity metric in fcluster package

Tags: linux, python-2.7, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, cosine-similarity

I use scipy.cluster.hierarchy to do a hierarchical clustering on a set of points using "cosine" similarity metric. As an example, I have:

```
import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as hac 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

Points = 
  np.array([[ 0.         , 0.23508573], 
 [ 0.00754775 , 0.26717266], 
 [ 0.00595464 , 0.27775905], 
 [ 0.01220563 , 0.23622067], 
 [ 0.00542628 , 0.14185873], 
 [ 0.03078922 , 0.11273108], 
 [ 0.06707743 ,-0.1061131 ], 
 [ 0.04411757 ,-0.10775407], 
 [ 0.01349434 , 0.00112159], 
 [ 0.04066034 , 0.11639591], 
 [ 0.         , 0.29046682], 
 [ 0.07338036 , 0.00609912], 
 [ 0.01864988 , 0.0316196 ], 
 [ 0.         , 0.07270636], 
 [ 0.         ,  0.        ]]) 


z = hac.linkage(Points, metric='cosine', method='complete') 
labels = hac.fcluster(z, 0.1, criterion="distance") 


plt.scatter(Points[:, 0], Points[:, 1], c=labels.astype(np.float)) 
plt.show()
```

Since I use cosine metric, in some cases the dot product of two vectors can be negative or norm of some vectors can be zero. It means z output will have some negative or infinite elements which is not valid for fcluster (as below):

```
z =
[[  0.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+01   0.00000000e+00   2.00000000e+00] 
[  1.30000000e+01   1.50000000e+01   0.00000000e+00   3.00000000e+00] 
[  8.00000000e+00   1.10000000e+01   4.26658708e-13   2.00000000e+00]       
[  1.00000000e+00   2.00000000e+00   2.31748880e-05   2.00000000e+00] 
[  3.00000000e+00   4.00000000e+00   8.96700489e-05   2.00000000e+00] 
[  1.60000000e+01   1.80000000e+01   3.98805492e-04   5.00000000e+00] 
[  1.90000000e+01   2.00000000e+01   1.33225099e-03   7.00000000e+00] 
[  5.00000000e+00   9.00000000e+00   2.41120340e-03   2.00000000e+00] 
[  6.00000000e+00   7.00000000e+00   1.52914684e-02   2.00000000e+00] 
[  1.20000000e+01   2.20000000e+01   3.52441432e-02   3.00000000e+00] 
[  2.10000000e+01   2.40000000e+01   1.38662986e-01   1.00000000e+01] 
[  1.70000000e+01   2.30000000e+01   6.99056531e-01   4.00000000e+00] 
[  2.50000000e+01   2.60000000e+01   1.92543748e+00   1.40000000e+01] 
[ -1.00000000e+00   2.70000000e+01              inf   1.50000000e+01]]
```

To solve this problem, I checked linkage() function and inside it I needed to check _hierarchy.linkage() method. I use pycharm text editor and when I asked for "linkage" source code, it opened up a python file namely "_hierarchy.py" inside the directory like the following:

```
.PyCharm40/system/python_stubs/-1247972723/scipy/cluster/_hierarchy.py
```

This python file doesn't have any definition for all included functions.
I am wondering what is the correct source of this function to revise it or is there another way to solve this problem. 
I would be appreciated for your helps and hints.

Answer (score 0):

You have a zero vector `0 0` in your data set. For such data, **cosine distance is undefined**, so you are using an inappropriate distance function!
This is a definition gap that cannot be trivially closed. `inf` is as incorrect as `0`. The distance to `0 0` with cosine *cannot* be defined without contraditions. You must not use cosine on such data.

Back to your actual question: `_hierarchy` is a Cython module. **It is not pure python, but it is compiled to native code**. You can easily see the source code on Github:

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/cluster/_hierarchy.pyx

Comment: Thanks @Anony-Mousse. I didn't see that `0 0` vector in my data set! I should correct other part of my code. Also thank you for the link. you helped me a lot.

Comment: Why do you think cosine distance is appropriate?

Comment: I use cosine distance to do hierarchical clustering on my data set. After I will make sum on all elements of each cluster. In fact I am looking for the approximate greatest vector in each cluster. Then, I think cosine similarity metric can be a good metric. something like in this figure : [figure](https://pegahalizadeh.wordpress.com/figure/). Do you suggest other metrics for my case?

Comment: You may be misinterpreting that picture! Everything on a line is considered to be identical by cosine (same angle!)